# postgres trigger function only inserts few records in another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables hourly and daily and my aim is to calculate average of values from hourly table and save it to daily table. I have written a trigger function like this -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calculate_daily_avg()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE chrly CURSOR for
SELECT device, date(datum) datum, avg(cpu_util) cpu_util
FROM chourly WHERE date(datum) = current_date group by device, date(datum);

BEGIN

    FOR chrly_rec IN chrly
    LOOP

    insert into cdaily (device, datum, cpu_util)
    values (chrly_rec.device, chrly_rec.datum, chrly_rec.cpu_util)
        on conflict (device, datum) do update set 
        device=chrly_rec.device, datum=chrly_rec.datum, cpu_util=chrly_rec.cpu_util;

    return NEW;

    END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'NO DATA IN chourly FOR %', current_date;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.calculate_daily_avg()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

and a trigger on hourly table like this -

```
CREATE TRIGGER calculate_daily_avg_trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.chourly
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.calculate_daily_avg();
```

But when I try to insert or update about 3000 records in the hourly table only 3 or 4 devices are inserted and not 3000. (also in trigger I have already tried AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE but even that gives the same result) What I am doing wrong here? Please suggest any better way to write the trigger if you feel I have written it wrongly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest using `TRIGGER` for calculation when `INSERT`. Try different approach using function execute by cron hourly or daily.

**WHY?**

Because everytime you `INSERT` one row. the postgres will always do aggregate function `AVG()` and `LOOPING` for insert (based on your flow).

That mean another `INSERT` statement will waiting until `Previous INSERT` commited that will suffer your database performance for highly `INSERT Transaction`. If somehow you manage to `BREAK` the rule (maybe from configuration) you will get `inconsistent` data like what happened to you right now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it well Adrian. If I need to stick to trigger then can't I somehow wait for all inserts in my trigger by adding a sleep? Cron approach seems to be better alternative nonetheless.

Comment: @dappler No you cant by adding sleep, Because you don't know exactly query execution time. if you somehow put sleep (let's say 20 sec) when high traffic is okay. but when low traffic the insert also wait 20 sec. we don't want that to happen. the cron approach is better than sacrifice your transaction performance and potential deadlock.

Comment: you make good point Adrian. I have replaced trigger function with just function and calling it from java. Thanks!